# How can I expand and collapse part of my form with QPropertyAnimation

Tags: c++, qt

I want is to show and collapse the groupBox by clicking on the button; so far it works, but i think its not the correct way to do.

The animation looks very bad when the form is expanded and when it is contracted it is a little more normal.

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class Widget; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();


private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
    QPropertyAnimation *animation;
    bool expand=false;
    int height;
};
#endif // WIDGET_H

#include "widget.h"
#include "./ui_widget.h"
#include <QDebug>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->pushButton->setText("expand");
    height=this->size().height();
    ui->groupBox->setVisible(false);


}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}


void Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    if(!expand){

        animation=new QPropertyAnimation(this,"size");
        animation->setDuration(250);
        animation->setEndValue(QSize(this->width(),height));
        animation->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InQuad);
        animation->start();
        ui->groupBox->setVisible(true);
        expand=true;
        ui->pushButton->setText("Shrink");


    }else{
        ui->groupBox->setVisible(false);
        animation=new QPropertyAnimation(this,"size");
        animation->setDuration(250);
        animation->setEndValue(QSize(this->width(),(height-ui->groupBox->size().height())));
        animation->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InQuad);
        animation->start();
        expand=false;
        ui->pushButton->setText("Expand");


    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: share the .ui file content

Comment: Maybe won't help with the look of the animation, but if you want to change only height, you can use only `maximumHeight` property.